# Replace value in table based on another table

Tags: javascript, arquero

Is there a best practice in using arquero to reformat a value based on a set of ranges?

For example,  I have the following 2 arrays:

```
const agefmt = [
       {
       'fmtname': 'agefmt',
       'type'  : 'n',
       'format': [
                  {'start': 0,  'end': 10, 'label': '0 - 10'},
                  {'start': 11, 'end': 20, 'label': '11 - 20'},
                  {'start': 21, 'end': 30, 'label': '21 - 30'},
                  {'start': 31, 'end': 40, 'label': '31 - 40'},
                  {'start': 41, 'end': 50, 'label': '41 - 50'},
                  {'start': 51, 'end': 1000, 'label': '>51'}
                 ]
       },  
]

const age = [
    { "AGE": 19 },
    { "AGE": 20 },
    { "AGE": 31 },
    { "AGE": 26 },
    { "AGE": 46 },
    { "AGE": 27 }
]
```

and I would like to replace the 'age' array with the 'label' within the range of the 'start' and 'end' values defined in the agefmt array.

The resulting array should look like the following:

```
[
    { "AGE": '0 - 10' },
    { "AGE": '11 - 20' },
    { "AGE": '31 - 40' },
    { "AGE": '21 - 30' },
    { "AGE": '41 - 60' },
    { "AGE": '21 - 30' }
]
```

I started writing it as a function like so, but found I couldn't pass the 'agefmt' as a parameter:

```
addFunction(function fmt({infmt, value})  { 
    console.log(value, infmt)
    // calculate ranges here
    return value 
});

r.derive({rowvar : d => op.fmt(rowgrp, d.rowvar)})
```

Is there a more obvious way to achieve this?

Comment: Note: based on your data, the first entry should have a label of `11 - 20` because the age is 19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a matter of iterating through the `age` array, and then checking the nested `AGE` property against `agefmt[0].format` in a for loop. Whenever the `AGE` value is between the `start` and `end` values, then a label is considered found and we break out of the for loop.

One thing is that your expected output is incorrect based on your provided data: the first entry has an age of `19` and the matching label should be `11 - 20` not `0 - 10` as you wanted.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const agefmt = [
  {
    fmtname: "agefmt",
    type: "n",
    format: [
      { start: 0, end: 10, label: "0 - 10" },
      { start: 11, end: 20, label: "11 - 20" },
      { start: 21, end: 30, label: "21 - 30" },
      { start: 31, end: 40, label: "31 - 40" },
      { start: 41, end: 50, label: "41 - 50" },
      { start: 51, end: 1000, label: ">51" },
    ],
  },
];

const age = [
  { AGE: 19 },
  { AGE: 20 },
  { AGE: 31 },
  { AGE: 26 },
  { AGE: 46 },
  { AGE: 27 },
];

function addLabelToAge(age, labelFormat) {
  return age.map(entry => {
    let matchedLabel = '';
    for (const format of labelFormat) {
      if (entry.AGE >= format.start && entry.AGE <= format.end) {
        matchedLabel = format.label;
        break;
      }
    }
    return { AGE: matchedLabel };
  });
}

console.log(addLabelToAge(age, agefmt[0].format));
```

If you're comfortable with ES6 syntax, you can make the function a little more concise using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) + [object property assignment shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions):

```
function addLabelToAge(age, labelFormat) {
  return age.map(({ AGE }) => {
    let matchedLabel = '';
    for (const { start, end, label } of labelFormat) {
      if (AGE >= start && AGE <= end) {
        matchedLabel = label;
        break;
      }
    }
    return { AGE: matchedLabel };
  });
}
```

Comment: I think you're right :-) I was looking for a shorthand way using the arquero library, but I was overthinking it as it's just as easy to write a simple function.